# A user friendly interface for Ternary Diagram (C++ and C#)

Tags: diagram, mesh, triangulation, ternary, delaunay

Does anybody know how to public a user friendly interface or code. I have just developed an interface to plot ternary diagrams. I know there are softwares that can do the same but with this one users can choose a specific zone in the ternary diagram to plot data (for instance this ability is needed in petroleum engineering). I also have codes in MATLAB, C++, C# for Delaunay triangulation, voroni diagram, meshing, and colormapping. I think maybe they are useful for others. I wish I could upload some pictures of my works but I need to have at least 10 reputations.

Thanks,